# How do I get the top highest values in an Array of Objects without using sort()

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an Array of objects which I need to perform tasks on.

Without using the `sort()` method I need to sort the objects inside of the array based on who voted for Trump , and who voted for Hillary.

Additionally I need to find the five states that voted most for Trump and find the five states that voted most for Hillary.

Here is the array:

```
var states = [{
  stateName: "Delaware",
  votesForHillary: 14,
  votesForTrump: 123,
  population: 925749
}, {
  stateName: "Pennsylvania",
  votesForHillary: 240,
  votesForTrump: 1,
  population: 12773801
}, {
  stateName: "New Jersey",
  votesForHillary: 124,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 8899339
}, {
  stateName: "Georgia",
  votesForHillary: 12,
  votesForTrump: 353,
  population: 9992167
}, {
  stateName: "Connecticut",
  votesForHillary: 23,
  votesForTrump: 135,
  population: 3596080
}, {
  stateName: "Massachusetts",
  votesForHillary: 50,
  votesForTrump: 53,
  population: 6692824
}, {
  stateName: "Maryland",
  votesForHillary: 424,
  votesForTrump: 23,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "South Carolina",
  votesForHillary: 0,
  votesForTrump: 1,
  population: 4774839
}, {
  stateName: "New Hampshire",
  votesForHillary: 34,
  votesForTrump: 14,
  population: 1323459
}, {
  stateName: "Virginia",
  votesForHillary: 233,
  votesForTrump: 153,
  population: 8260405
}, {
  stateName: "New York",
  votesForHillary: 253,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 19651127
}, {
  stateName: "North Carolina",
  votesForHillary: 5,
  votesForTrump: 404,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "Rhode Island",
  votesForHillary: 4,
  votesForTrump: 6,
  population: 1051511
}, {
  stateName: "Vermont",
  votesForHillary: 23,
  votesForTrump: 54,
  population: 626630
}, {
  stateName: "Kentucky",
  votesForHillary: 46,
  votesForTrump: 647,
  population: 4395295
}, {
  stateName: "Tennessee",
  votesForHillary: 44,
  votesForTrump: 600,
  population: 6495978
}, {
  stateName: "Ohio",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 45,
  population: 11570808
}, {
  stateName: "Louisiana",
  votesForHillary: 65,
  votesForTrump: 56,
  population: 4625470
}, {
  stateName: "Indiana",
  votesForHillary: 21,
  votesForTrump: 12,
  population: 6570902
}, {
  stateName: "Mississippi",
  votesForHillary: 340,
  votesForTrump: 151,
  population: 2991207
}, {
  stateName: "Illinois",
  votesForHillary: 114,
  votesForTrump: 53,
  population: 12882135
}, {
  stateName: "Alabama",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 1351,
  population: 4833722
}, {
  stateName: "Maine",
  votesForHillary: 1,
  votesForTrump: 2,
  population: 1328302
}, {
  stateName: "Missouri",
  votesForHillary: 240,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 6044171
}, {
  stateName: "Arkansas",
  votesForHillary: 53,
  votesForTrump: 153,
  population: 2959373
}, {
  stateName: "Michigan",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 647,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "Florida",
  votesForHillary: 46,
  votesForTrump: 474,
  population: 19552860
}, {
  stateName: "Texas",
  votesForHillary: 0,
  votesForTrump: 0,
  population: 26448193
}, {
  stateName: "Iowa",
  votesForHillary: 436,
  votesForTrump: 123,
  population: 3090416
}, ];
```

and here is the way i did it with the sort() method.

```js
states.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.votesForTrump - a.votesForTrump;
});
```

It's not homework it is a challenge I am trying to understand.

Comment: why no sort? does it have a reason?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Homework assignments are already a bit of a controversial topic, but without any attempt from your side, you will most likely not get any answers.

Comment: Why you would not use supporting methods is questionable and makes this question sound like homework or similar. If that's the case, without using `sort()` or similar methods you need to loop through all of the objects yourself and record min, max values. There is plenty of examples out there (simple google etc...) how to loop. Try one of them and if you have issues post your code here and we have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Next time , please show some of your own effort before seeking assistance;

For your issue, a combination of `map`,`filter`,`Math.max` is needed;

```js
var states = [{
  stateName: "Delaware",
  votesForHillary: 14,
  votesForTrump: 123,
  population: 925749
}, {
  stateName: "Pennsylvania",
  votesForHillary: 240,
  votesForTrump: 1,
  population: 12773801
}, {
  stateName: "New Jersey",
  votesForHillary: 124,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 8899339
}, {
  stateName: "Georgia",
  votesForHillary: 12,
  votesForTrump: 353,
  population: 9992167
}, {
  stateName: "Connecticut",
  votesForHillary: 23,
  votesForTrump: 135,
  population: 3596080
}, {
  stateName: "Massachusetts",
  votesForHillary: 50,
  votesForTrump: 53,
  population: 6692824
}, {
  stateName: "Maryland",
  votesForHillary: 424,
  votesForTrump: 23,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "South Carolina",
  votesForHillary: 0,
  votesForTrump: 1,
  population: 4774839
}, {
  stateName: "New Hampshire",
  votesForHillary: 34,
  votesForTrump: 14,
  population: 1323459
}, {
  stateName: "Virginia",
  votesForHillary: 233,
  votesForTrump: 153,
  population: 8260405
}, {
  stateName: "New York",
  votesForHillary: 253,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 19651127
}, {
  stateName: "North Carolina",
  votesForHillary: 5,
  votesForTrump: 404,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "Rhode Island",
  votesForHillary: 4,
  votesForTrump: 6,
  population: 1051511
}, {
  stateName: "Vermont",
  votesForHillary: 23,
  votesForTrump: 54,
  population: 626630
}, {
  stateName: "Kentucky",
  votesForHillary: 46,
  votesForTrump: 647,
  population: 4395295
}, {
  stateName: "Tennessee",
  votesForHillary: 44,
  votesForTrump: 600,
  population: 6495978
}, {
  stateName: "Ohio",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 45,
  population: 11570808
}, {
  stateName: "Louisiana",
  votesForHillary: 65,
  votesForTrump: 56,
  population: 4625470
}, {
  stateName: "Indiana",
  votesForHillary: 21,
  votesForTrump: 12,
  population: 6570902
}, {
  stateName: "Mississippi",
  votesForHillary: 340,
  votesForTrump: 151,
  population: 2991207
}, {
  stateName: "Illinois",
  votesForHillary: 114,
  votesForTrump: 53,
  population: 12882135
}, {
  stateName: "Alabama",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 1351,
  population: 4833722
}, {
  stateName: "Maine",
  votesForHillary: 1,
  votesForTrump: 2,
  population: 1328302
}, {
  stateName: "Missouri",
  votesForHillary: 240,
  votesForTrump: 15,
  population: 6044171
}, {
  stateName: "Arkansas",
  votesForHillary: 53,
  votesForTrump: 153,
  population: 2959373
}, {
  stateName: "Michigan",
  votesForHillary: 35,
  votesForTrump: 647,
  population: 600000
}, {
  stateName: "Florida",
  votesForHillary: 46,
  votesForTrump: 474,
  population: 19552860
}, {
  stateName: "Texas ",
  votesForHillary: 0,
  votesForTrump: 0,
  population: 26448193
}, {
  stateName: "Iowa",
  votesForHillary: 436,
  votesForTrump: 123,
  population: 3090416
}, ];

let trumpStates = states.filter((data) => {return data["votesForTrump"] > data["votesForHillary"]});
let hillaryStates = states.filter((data) => {return data["votesForTrump"] < data["votesForHillary"]});

let allTrumpVotes = [];
let allHillaryVotes = [];

trumpStates.map((data) => allTrumpVotes.push(data["votesForTrump"]));

hillaryStates.map((data) => allHillaryVotes.push(data["votesForHillary"]));

let maxTrumpVotes = Math.max(...allTrumpVotes);
let maxHillaryVotes = Math.max(...allHillaryVotes);
console.log(allHillaryVotes)
let maxTrumpState = trumpStates.filter((data) => {
  if(data["votesForTrump"] == maxTrumpVotes) return data;
  });
  
 let maxHillaryState = hillaryStates.filter((data) => {
  if(data["votesForHillary"] == maxHillaryVotes) return data;
  });
console.log(maxHillaryState,maxTrumpState)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function will help on sorting stuff and also you can do same sorting to get most votes states for Hillary.

```
    function sorting() {
    console.log("Lenght : " + states.length);

    let TopVotedToTrump: typeof states;
    let TopVotedToHillary: typeof states;
    TopVotedToTrump.push(states[0]);
    for (let i: number = 0; i < states.length-1 ; i++) {
        for (let j: number = i + 1; j < states.length; j++) {
            if ((states[i].votesForTrump < states[j].votesForTrump) || (states[i].votesForTrump == states[j].votesForTrump && states[i].votesForHillary < states[j].votesForHillary))
            {
                console.log(states[i].votesForTrump + " swapped with " + states[j].votesForTrump);
                let temp = states[i];
                states[i] = states[j]
                states[j] = temp
            }
            if ((states[i].votesForHillary < states[j].votesForHillary)) {
                let temp = states[i];
                states[i] = states[j]
                states[j] = temp
            }
        }

        if (TopVotedToTrump.indexOf(states[i]) != -1) {
            TopVotedToTrump.push(states[i]);
        }
    }

    //for (let i of states) {
    //    console.log("{" + " State: " + i.stateName + " Population: " + i.population + " Votes For Hillary: " + i.votesForHillary + " Votes For Trump: "+ i.votesForTrump + "}");
    //}
    //console.log("Result : " + JSON.parse(states.toString()));
}
```